# Enterprise Architect Base Line delete

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any way to capture the event of deletion of a base line from Enterprise Architect?
EA supports methods which can poll the currently opened EA Repository and inform my addin that a diagram/element/connector/package is getting deleted from the model. However, for base line, there is no such method provided which I can over ride and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of EA 11, there is no support for this in the API. The workaround would be to create a database trigger, which would kick your Add-In on baseline delete. Baselines are stored in the `t_document` table, with the `DocType` column set to "Baseline".

Of course, this would mean altering the database schema, which I always advise against. In addition, if you want to create a generic Add-In which supports all the database engines EA can run on, it'll be a fair bit of work. But if it's for an in-house Add-In where you know the repositories are always on the same engine, it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there is no such API function. However, fiddling with baselines can be restricted with security. So the best advice is to use that.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "So the best advice is to use that"

Comment: I guessed that the reason for intercepting the deletion was to prevent someone from doing it (accidentally). And if you turn on security you can do exactly that.